# How too not display button content of a blog post in metadata blog preview wordpress?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I would like to customize an article meta description on WordPress.
[Metadata with "Lire l'article"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Plo1.png) 
When I am on the blog page I would like the meta-description of the article to contain only the text and not the text contained in the button present in the article.
[Button content too not display in metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ss1S.png)
Is there a code in css to display only the textual content and not the button?

See the attached example.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try CSS pointer-events Property
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp

Comment: Thanks but how does it work ? I use elementor builder and JupiterX template